# Подсветка выбранных полей в форме

Tags: javascript, select, html-form

Есть форма с select'ами.
При отправке формы выбранные значения select'ов сохраняются.
Задача - после отправки формы присвоить css-класс select'ам, в которых выбраны непустые значения (т.е. присутствуют option'ы с присвоенным selected).

Может, кто знает подходящий *javascript*?

Comment: А если на php? Или страница html+js?

Comment: там Smarty, я уже решил вопрос, благодарю    document.getElementById("myselect").className += "active-select"; правда, пришлось таки через смарти ставить условия

Comment: Ответили бы на свой вопрос, в будущем людям может быть помогло бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C помощью `css` можно создать запрос на отмеченный `options` ( `option[selected]` ), но уже нельзя будет обратится вверх к `select`.
Говорят что скоро появится псевдокласс `:has` с помощью которого можно будет проверить уже сам `select` на вхождение нужного селектора. Но даже если он появится завтра, то в реальности можно будет использовать ещё не скоро. Поэтому сейчас только с помощью `javascript` -

```
// получаем все option с selected
let selected = document.body.querySelectorAll( 'option[selected]' );
// преобразуем в массив с select
let selectAll = Array.from( selected ).map( item => item.closest( 'select' ) );
// добавляем какие-то классы
selectAll.forEach( select => select.classList.add( 'some-class' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

По просьбе @Winteriscoming отвечу на свой вопрос, но боюсь, что ответ таки не всем пригодится.

В общем и целом, проблема решается при помощи javascript одной строчкой

```
document.getElementById("myselect").className += "active-select";
```

То есть, мы присваиваем селекту #myselect дополнительно класс .active-select, который задаёт подсветку.

Но, загвоздка в том, что это надо делать только в случае, если в селекте уже выбрано значение. У меня страница использует smarty, поэтому, я могу поставить условие, например так.

```
<option value="{$vendor.id}" {if $vendor.id == 1}selected="selected" вот сюда добавив переменную {$controller="1"}{/if}>{$vendor.title}</option>
```

А потом уже выполнять скрипт при условии, если

```
                    {if $controller == 1}
                    {literal}
                        <script>
                        document.getElementById("id_vendor").className += "active-select";
                        </script>
                    {/literal}
                    {/if}
```

Вот как-то так. Уверен, что на javascript можно было как-то отследить параметр selected на его наличие, и тогда уже присваивать класс. Но со smarty я быстрей догадался))